# URL for FileField

Tags: django, filefield

What is the most simple solution to such a problem:
use models.FileField for local file or models.CharField for entering URL, depends on an option which were switched before.
The next code does not work, but shows the idea:

```
class T(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    if type == 2:
        attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.ATTACHEMENTS_FOLDER, blank=True, max_length=255)
    else:
        attachment = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store it with in the `Type` model.
That way it can be whatever field is correct. And you have flexibility of adding more types later.

Comment: `Type` should store the URL or file location. Then you can get it with  `T.type.attachment`

Comment: No, the question is how to update the attachment field on the add dialog regarding type 1 or 2 has been chosen.

Comment: Well, the form will handle that. If the form `instance` is `Type.type1`, then the attachment field will be whatever field is defined for that `Type`.

Comment: If you are going to change the field on the fly, then you will need to use some client-side scripting.